# Node forge very bad performance in RSA decrypt

Tags: node.js, performance, encryption, rsa, node-forge

```
// Decrypt using RSA
const privateKey = Forge.pki.privateKeyFromPem("Key.......");

const decryptedKey = privateKey.decrypt(convertedKey);
const decryptedIv = privateKey.decrypt(convertedIv);
```

I use node forge to decrypt key and iv of AES. I notice that the performance are very bad.

Each decryption is completed in about 400 ms AVG.

Is it possible to increase performance or i need to change library?

Comment: You can double the performance by not encrypting the IV.

Comment: Explaining the previous comment - IV can be passed as cleartext, it doesn't need to be secret. RSA itself is  cpu demanding,